# How to ensure a TreeNode is visible

Tags: node.js, tree, treenode, blueprintjs

In my app, I'm trying to make sure the selected treenode is shown, meaning it is expanded all the way down, and also scrolled into view.

How can I **programmatically** implement this (meaning all the tree node's parent nodes are expanded, and it's scrolled into view)?

A tree node only has a reference to its children, not its parent, and there's no way I could find to scroll the tree to a node.

I have tried to look for `ITreeNode.EnsureVisible` method or similar, but in vain.

Comment: What's `Treenode` a library? What have you tried? Any code you can share.

Comment: I'm using blueprintjs, a React-based UI toolkit (thought this was clear from the "blueprintjs" tag.

Comment: Can you go top-down? "if the selected node is in my children, then expand (and return `true`)", where that test is a recursive function?